# How do I tell mxmlc to treat warnings as errors?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, compiler-construction, mxmlc

I'm using the mxmlc command line tool to compile a pure AS3 project. **Is there a command line option to make mxmlc treat warnings as errors?** I've read through all the compiler flags and flex-config.xml but wasn't able to find this option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. The default mxmlc value for 'strict' is true. Setting it to true has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

What about...

```
-compiler.strict
```

*alias -strict 
runs the AS3 compiler in strict error checking mode. strict must be 
'false' when es3 is 'true'*.

I believe you can just use:

```
mxmlc --strict=true
```

Comment: This still does not tell the compiler to treat warnings as errors :(