# Actionscript 3.0 warning as error

Tags: actionscript-3, warnings, adobe-flash-cs3

Is it possible to configure Adobe Flash CS3 ActionScript to make it treating warnings as errors?

Comment: Be careful with this one if you're using third-party libraries. Flash will warn you if your variables are untyped, which is the case in many third-party libraries (for various reasons; many are legitimate). Converting warnings to errors would break compilation for these libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Flash is a bit of a different beast, you've got "warnings" mode and "strict" mode. They're both enabled by default and strict mode is the best you're going to get. The "warnings" that you see are typically just warnings to let you know if you're using a deprecated method or have duplicate variable names etc. Sources:

http://www.bytearray.org/?p=931

May be of interest if you're using the flex compiler: 
[How do I tell mxmlc to treat warnings as errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180691/how-do-i-tell-mxmlc-to-treat-warnings-as-errors)